# Ninject and WCF Web Services make Entity Framework slow

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, ninject

I have the next setup: WCF Web Services hosted in IIS. Entity Framework 6 used to retrieve data from the DB. Web Services are initialized in the Global.asax.cs, which inherits from NinjectHttpApplication (so we use ninject for dependency injection). In this NinjectHttpApplication, on the CreateKernel method we bind the EF DbContext as follows:

```
protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<MyCustomContext>().InTransientScope();
    return kernel;
}
```

Then, every time a service is called, the Context is obtained as follows in its consturctor:

```
_context = kernel.Get<DbContext>();
```

Then, the service retrieves data from the DB as follows:

```
data = _context.Set<TEntity>().Where(<whatever filter>);
```

Having said that, my problem is the next: I have a service which is being called many times (with a complex and long query with multple joins), and every time it is called, EF takes ages to produce SQL to send to the DB as result of the Linq To Entities that I've coded. The execution of the query in the DB is nothing (600 milliseconds) but EF is taking ages to produce the SQL every single time this service is called. I suspect this is because of `kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<MyContext>().InTransientScope()` who is forcing EF to create a new instance of the DbContext every time there is a call.

I've made a few tests with UnitTests and the behavior is totally different: if you instantiate the service multiple times from the same unit test method and you call it, EF takes long to produce the query only the first time, then it takes no time to produce SQL from the subsequent calls (same query but with different parameters to filter the data to retrieve). From the unit test, the CreateKernel() is of course only called once in the `Initialize()` method (like in the Web Service in the global.asax.cs), so I dont know what is provoking this huge delay. I suspect EF is capable to keep/cache the query pre-compiled with the unit test approach but not in the real web application. Any clue why?

Please note that the Linq to Entities query is parameterized (strings and date are the params).

Any help very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I find you bind your DbContext in a InTransientScope, which means every time you get Dbcontext from ninject , it will create a new DbContext for you.

You could consider using InThreadScope() instead of InTransientScope(), which means ninject will return the same instance when it is in the same thread.

There is also SingleTon scope , which means always returning the same instance ,but this will make the dbcontext too big.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried with both approaches (Singleton and Thread) and it helps with the "EF warm up" but still, the query takes ages to be "translated" to SQL (execution in the DB is milliseconds). I've read about the pre-compiled queries: According to the documentation I read, EF6 does it automatically (when no "Contains" method is included) but in my case the query is compiled and generated every time coz takes ages too. Any idea why?